# Display parent and multiple child entries in one row

Tags: sql

I'm searching for the best way to display parent and child entries in one row. There can be more children per parent. Example:

**PARENT Table:**

| P_ID | P_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABLE |
| 2 | BRUCE |
| 3 | CARL |

**CHILD TABLE:**

| C_ID | P_ID | C_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | QUIL |
| 2 | 1 | YEN |
| 3 | 2 | MAT |

**OUTPUT REQUIRED:**

| P_ID | P_VALUE | C_ID1 | C_VALUE1 | C_ID2 | C_VALUE2 | ----C_IDn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABLE | 1 | QUIL | 2 | YEN | -----n |
| 2 | BRUCE | 3 | MAT | NULL | NULL | ------n |
| 3 | CARL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | ------n |

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I think, "pivot" could help you. See here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql

Comment: As @h.m.i.13 mentioned, you need to research on 'pivot' or 'cross tabulation' approaches for getting your desired output. T-SQL and MySQL approach would be very different to tackle this. Be ready to spend considerable time to study :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i need a dynamic way that works with multiple child details. For 1 p_id, number of c_id is not fix.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags. [Edit] your question to retag the RDBMS you are *really* using. SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) and MySQL don't mix.